# Creating custom ExpandableListView, how to bind to "GroupTemplate" in axml

Tags: mvvmcross

I've created a bindable version of ExpandableListView based off of https://github.com/hlogmans/MvvmCross.DeapExtensions/ and put it in my app.  I want to add a GroupTemplate that I can bind to in the axml which would be similar to MvxListView's ItemTemplate.

Do I need to subclass MvxAndroidBindingResource?  I'm also confused as to how the MvxBindingAttributes fits in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest route for this might be for you to take a read through how `MvxListView` and `MvxAdapter` work.

The `MvxBindingAttributes` (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/nuspec/DroidContent/MvxBindingAttributes.xml) allow MvvmCross to add new xml tags to the `axml` files.

The `MvxAndroidBindingResource` class (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/ResourceHelpers/MvxAndroidBindingResource.cs) is the C# code to parse the values for the attribute tags defined in `MvxBindingAttributes`.

You can see this in action for an `MvxListView` in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs#L33

```
    public MvxListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapter adapter)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        // Note: Any calling derived class passing a null adapter is responsible for setting
        // it's own itemTemplateId
        if (adapter == null) 
            return;

        var itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
        adapter.ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId;
        Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

In particular, the line:

```
 var itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
```

This uses the id values parsed in `MvxAndroidBindingResource` to read the axml tag value for `local:MvxItemTemplate`